# Warning see reference to function Шаблоны C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++, warning

При запуске проекта все работает без сбоев.
Не могу избавиться от следующего Warning

```
C:\Agent\AgentApp\Include\Device.h(128) : see reference to function template instantiation 'T MessageHandler::GetValueFromMsgByIdParam<T>(const MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          Source\Device.cpp(422) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void Device::Set<int>(const MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner &, Object<T> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
```

Пример кода:

Шаблонный класс объекта

```
template <typename T>
class Object
{
public:
       Object(const T& _value) 
       {
          m_value = _value;
       }

   virtual void SetValue(const T& _value);
private:
   T m_value;
};

template <typename T>
void  Object<T>::SetValue(const T& _value)
{
   m_value = _value;
}
```

Вспомогательный класс для работы с сообщениями

```
class MessageHandler
{

public:
   MessageHandler();

   typedef vector<uint8_t> TMsgConteiner;

   template<typename T>
   T  GetValueFromMsg(const TMsgConteiner& _msg);
};

template<typename T>
T  MessageHandler::GetValueFromMsg(const TMsgConteiner& _msg)
{
   T f1((T)_msg.at(1));
   return f1;
}
```

Класс предоставляющий интерфейс устройства

```
class Device
{
public:
   Device();

   //! @brief Устанавливаем значение параметра с оборудования.
   template<typename T>
   void  Set(const TMsgConteiner& _msg, Object<T>& _obj);

   void GetCurrentConf();

protected:
   MessageHandler m_messageHandler;

   void  ReceiveAnswer(TMsgConteiner& _msg);
};

template<typename T>
void Device::Set(const TMsgConteiner& _msg, Object<T>& _obj)
{

      _obj.SetValue(m_messageHandler.GetValueFromMsg<T>(_msg));
}

void Device::GetCurrentConf()
{
      Object<int> obj(0);
      TMsgConteiner msg;

      ReceiveAnswer(msg);

      Set<int>(msg, obj);
}
```

Собственно использую данный код

```
int main()
{
    Device dev();
    dev.GetCurrentConf();

    return 0;
}
```

Первый see reference указывает на

```
template<typename T>
void Device::Set(const TMsgConteiner& _msg, Object<T>& _obj)
{
       // Именно на эту строку кода
      _obj.SetValue(m_messageHandler.GetValueFromMsg<T>(_msg));
}
```

Второй see reference указывает на

```
void Device::GetCurrentConf()
{
      Object<int> obj(0);
      TMsgConteiner msg;

      ReceiveAnswer(msg);

      // Именно на эту строку кода
      Set<int>(msg, obj);
}
```

Просьба сильно не ругать за оформление, всегда готов к редактированию.
Необходимы ваши советы. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Ушел на обед, через 40 минут дам все ответы и подробности

Comment: посмотри тут: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/25171/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде есть целый ряд ошибок:

1. Тип `TMsgConteiner` задан внутри класса `MessageHandler`. Стало быть и использоваться извне должен как `MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner`.
2. `Device dev();` это не создание объекта типа `Device` с именем `dev`, а объявление функции `dev`, которая возвращает результат типа `Device`. См. "most vexing parce".
3. Доступ к элементам вектора через функцию-член `at()` кидает исключение при выходе за границы. Поэтому надо добавить обработку исключения.

С учетом описанных замечаний и пустых реализаций (заглушек) необходимых функций получается следующий код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Object
{
public:
   Object(const T& _value) 
   {
      m_value = _value;
   }

   virtual void SetValue(const T& _value);
private:
   T m_value;
};

template <typename T>
void  Object<T>::SetValue(const T& _value)
{
   m_value = _value;
}

class MessageHandler
{

public:
   MessageHandler() {};

   typedef vector<uint8_t> TMsgConteiner;

   template<typename T>
   T  GetValueFromMsg(const TMsgConteiner& _msg);
};

template<typename T>
T  MessageHandler::GetValueFromMsg(const TMsgConteiner& _msg)
{
   T f1((T)_msg.at(1));
   return f1;
}

class Device
{
public:
   Device() {};

   //! @brief Устанавливаем значение параметра с оборудования.
   template<typename T>
   void  Set(const MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner& _msg, Object<T>& _obj);

   void GetCurrentConf();

protected:
   MessageHandler m_messageHandler;

   void  ReceiveAnswer(MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner& _msg) {};
};

template<typename T>
void Device::Set(const MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner& _msg, Object<T>& _obj)
{
      _obj.SetValue(m_messageHandler.GetValueFromMsg<T>(_msg));
}

void Device::GetCurrentConf()
{
      Object<int> obj(0);
      MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner msg;

     ReceiveAnswer(msg);

      Set<int>(msg, obj);
}

int main()
{
    Device dev;

    try {
        dev.GetCurrentConf();
    }
    catch(...) { // better catch specific exception type
       // do nothing
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вживую [тут](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62e914625cff956b).

Answer (score 0):

Все описанные замечания мне известны.
Я думал так будет меньше кода.
И вопрос будет более краток.

Ошибка оказалась в следующем.

Я от нее избавился, когда писал вопрос.
Это вариант, который я положил в вопрос.

```
template<typename T>
T  MessageHandler::GetValueFromMsg(const TMsgConteiner& _msg)
{
   T f1((T)_msg.at(1));
   return f1;
}
```

Избавляясь от избыточности кода, я удалил один из входных параметров, которые не использовал.

```
template<typename T>
T  MessageHandler::GetValueFromMsgById(const unsigned int _id ,const TMsgConteiner& _msg)
{
   T f1((T)_msg.at(1));
   return f1;
}
```

Из-за него сыпался Warning

```
warning C4100: '_id_cmd' : unreferenced formal parameter
  see reference to function template instantiation 'T MessageHandler::GetValueFromMsgByIdParam<T>(const MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          Source\Device.cpp(422) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void Device::Set<int>(const MessageHandler::TMsgConteiner &, Object<T> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
```

Я не знал, что именно это вызывает  "see reference to"
Извиняюсь за недостающую строку warninga, вам бы не пришлось копаться в замечаниях.

Comment: Даже стыдно.
понедельник после бурного воскресенья.
Еще раз сорян